# Multiple IDs to one fact table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following example where I have in the Code mapping table two IDs which one relates to the current year ID and the second to the prior year ID. It is important to map them against eachother so that we can do calculations such as current year net revenue vs. prior year net revenue.

I am struggling to figure out the best way to structure the data model vs. how much to takle with DAX. Any ideas on the best way to model it?

[image]

Comment: I have attached a simplified PBIX file below. The only thing to note is that there could be multiple rows in the Fact table for the same client code, therefore the measures would need to aggregate.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rcMj8VxbSgG3yy9JVvQuFaGbroLs4OXr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your query, the current year & prior year are distinct dimensions so your model should have 2 dimension tables that are linked separately to the fact table, rather than trying to link the fact table to the same dimension table twice. The source ClientcodeJobcodes table would be the same for each of the 2 dimensions but would appear twice in your data model (e.g. ClientcodeJobcodesCurrent & ClientcodeJobcodesPrior).